# Как привязать функцию к селектору? (возможно ли?)

Tags: jquery

Можно как-то привязать функцию к селектору? Чтобы она выполнялась, если селектор найдет что-нибудь?

```
  $( "div.mydiv" ).function(){
      console.log('work!');
    };
```

Comment: Зачем? Предрекаю XY problem.

Comment: Да хотя бы для тестирования селектора, верно ли сформирован.

Comment: Это легко делается через `console.log($(selector));`, количество элементов отслеживается через `.length` или `.size()`.

Comment: @Vitalik Z Для тестирования селектора не нужно ничего привязывать. Достаточно просто проверить условие: `if ($( "div.mydiv" ).length) {...}`

Comment: Ребят, давайте по теме. Можно 100500 применений найти.

Comment: @Vitalik Z Здесь решают **конкретные** проблемы, а не сферические. Опишите вашу конкретную проблему, только тогда вы получите ответ.

Comment: Vitalik Z, это классическая XY problem. У вас есть проблема, вы придумали как ее решить (и это плохое решение, поверьте), но о реальной проблеме не рассказываете. Если вам нужно смотреть, что селектор нашел, то это делается снаружи, а не изнутри.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Протестировать селектор можно и способом по проще:

```
$("div.mydiv").length;
```

Например: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/guvwnpgu/

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

console.log($(".a").length); // 2
console.log($(".b").length); // 1
console.log($(".c").length); // 0
```

Если все же очень нужно выполнять какой-то код, то вам поможет each: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/guvwnpgu/1/

```
$(".a").each(function () { // выполнится 2 раза
    console.log("A is here");
});
$(".b").each(function () { // выполнится 1 раз
    console.log("B is here");
});
$(".c").each(function () { // не выполнится
    console.log("C is here");
});
```